# Where is the Xampp mailoutput folder on mac?

Tags: php, macos, email, xampp

I know on windows has  C:\xampp\mailoutput folder

However, where is the same folder on mac?

(I want to test out sending email on localhost, and someone said I can find the email that already sent through C:\xampp\mailoutput folder , so I have to find the same folder on mac in order to see my mails )

Answer (score 0):

There is no`mailoutput`  folder in XAMPP macOS version, instead you can use the default mail folder in macOS, like this:

1. Go to `xampp/etc/` to edit `php.ini` within `[mail function]`
2. Replace this line `;sendmail_path =` with `sendmail_path = "env -i /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -I"`

   Now you can send mail with PHP in your XAMPP server, So to check the sent mails you need to:
3. Go to `/var/mail/` folder.
4. Open the `daemon` text file and you will find all mails listed there.

Answer (score -1):

default install path is : `/Applications/XAMPP`

Comment: Yes, but I am looking for the mail output  folder. i didn't see any folder name that.